# CKEditor and ASP.Net MVC 3 RequiredAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, asp.net-mvc-3

I've integrated CKEditor 3 (formerly FCKEditor) into my asp.net MVC (v3 to be specific) application. I have a RequiredAttribute in my model for the field that needs the editor but the client side validation doesn't work correctly with CKEditor. When I try to submit and I've entered data into CKEditor the required validation doesn't see the data. If I try resubmitting again, then it works. I've looked around online and can't find a solution. I am also using Jquery and using the Jquery adapter

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard solve. The problem is most likely that the validation runs before CKEditor transfers it's text to the textarea. I have the same problem. If I get time to look at it I will post the solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If someone is looking for a more generic way to do this you can add this javascript :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.text-editor')) {
        $('.text-editor').ckeditor();
        $('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function() {
            $('.text-editor').ckeditorGet().updateElement();
        });
    }
    });
```

And use .text-editor css class on a textarea and it works just fine.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "text-editor" })
```

I find this solution eazyer than the other one, hope it can helps!

Comment: since jquery validation 1.9, hidden fields are ignored, you have to put $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' }); not inside $(document).ready

Answer (score 6):

It is even simpler if you don't use the jQuery adapter:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        CKEDITOR.instances.Body.updateElement();
    });
});
```

Where Body is the ID of the textarea.

Answer (score 5):

For me this code does the trick, it could probably be optimized a bit but it works:

```
$('#newsForm').submit(function (event) {
     var editor = $('#Body').ckeditorGet();
     editor.updateElement();
     $(this).validate().form();
});
```

Because I don't know in which order the eventhandlers for submit runs I make sure to both update the value and refresh the validation result.

EDIT: Updated solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Body').ckeditor();
        $('#newsForm').bind('submit', onFirstSubmit);
    });

    function onFirstSubmit(event) {
        var editor = $('#Body').ckeditorGet();
        editor.updateElement();
        $(this).validate().form();
        $(this).unbind('submit', onFirstSubmit).submit();
    }

    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: The error client error went away but now the form isnt submitting

Comment: Forgot to submit the form again. Sorry. Updated the answer

Comment: Hmm, I think I got it to work but there are some weird issues I will have to look into first. Will look at it after work.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it fixed with the above solutions, but this worked for me;

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        CKEDITOR.replace("activiteit_details", { toolbar: 'Basic' });
        CKEDITOR.replace("activiteit_verslag", { toolbar: 'Full' });


        // Bind CKeditor fields on submit (To avoid problems with the RequiredAttribute)
        $('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function () {

            var CKactiviteit_details = CKEDITOR.instances.activiteit_details.getData();
            $("#activiteit_details").val(CKactiviteit_details);

            var CKactiviteit_verslag = CKEDITOR.instances.activiteit_verslag.getData();
            $("#activiteit_verslag").val(CKactiviteit_verslag);
        });

    });


</script>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

...

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.activiteit_details)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.activiteit_details)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.activiteit_details)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.activiteit_verslag)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.activiteit_verslag)

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.activiteit_verslag)
    </div>

...
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Opslaan" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to use CKEditor but with no luck. I've been using [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor) instead (along with the required attribute) and it works fine for me.

Ever thought of trying this instead?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers.
Thanks to this post I've found my own solution which suits my case perfectly.

If you don't want to use click/mousedown event, but instead, want to trigger the validation on the right form-submit event you can use the following approach.

It doesn't use neither jQuery-Adapter CKEditor plugin nor click event.
And it's possible to apply it to all forms with ckeditor.

```
$('form').on('submit.ckeditorValidation', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $ckeditor = $this.find('textarea.ckeditor');

    // if no ckeditor for this form then do nothing
    if (!$ckeditor || !$ckeditor.length) {
        return true;
    }

    // update content from CKEditor to TextArea
    var textAreaId = $ckeditor.attr('id');
    CKEDITOR.instances[textAreaId].updateElement();

    // trigger validation and check if the form is valid
    if (!$this.valid()) {
        return false;
    }

    // if form is valid then
    // unsubscribe current event handler to avoid endless recursion
    // and re-trigger form submit
    $(this).off('submit.ckeditorValidation').submit();
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i have been through the same issue and i was unable to resolve it because of one more issue that is related to it.

When ckeditor replaces the textarea, it makes it hidden and i found out that the default settings for jquery validator was to ignore the hidden elements with ":hidden" selector.

To resolve the issue, i have to update the hidden selector and update the element value. here is my code that does this in document ready event and is now working

```
$('#frmid').validate().settings.ignore = "input:hidden";
            $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
                $("#txtarea").val(CKEDITOR.instances["txtarea"].getData());
            });
```