# Add required field validation to text area rendering ckeditor in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor

i have a text area to which i have applied the ckeditor class. i want the text area as required field. I have added the code of the view. How can I achieve it?
tried couple of solutions from [CKEditor and ASP.Net MVC 3 RequiredAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491316/ckeditor-and-asp-net-mvc-3-requiredattribute), but no result.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.faq_answer)
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.faq_answer, new { @class = "ckeditor form-control", @id = "faq_answer" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.faq_answer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

My model property

```
    [Display(Name ="Answer")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter Answer")]
    public string faq_answer { get; set; }
```

Comment: in your class add [Required] attribute to "faq_answer" field.

Comment: i have added.  [Display(Name ="Answer")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter Answer")]
        public string faq_answer { get; set; }

Comment: You need to configure the validator to validate hidden inputs (ckeditor hides your input and replaces it with its own html)

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379307/jquery-chosen-dropdown-validation-client-site-doesnt-work/26392882#26392882)

Comment: after adding that, its working, but i m facing a issue, where even if i enter the text in the ckeditor on submitting it ll show the error message and on second click the data is submitted. how can i solve this issue?

Comment: @AshitaShah, If you have a new question then you need to ask a new question (showing the relevant code and the error message)